# Numerical integration when variable is lower limit

Tags: matlab

I need to calculate the following integral in matlab

\int_x^1 f(t) dt

Where I have f(t) as a vector of numbers. I know cumtrapz does from 0 to x, but how do you do it when it is from x to 1?

Comment: What have you tried? I'm pretty sure `cumtrapz` can do this for you, but without further context we can't really tell.

Comment: I am not sure what further context you need. I have vector which are samples of the function f(t) and I need to solve the above integral. I think the comment below about breaking up the limits might work.

Comment: I believe it's a consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus that for any real-valued function `f` and limits `a` and `b`, `int(f, a,b) == -int(f, b,a)`. So indeed, as answered by wlyles, use `flipud` or `fliplr` on your `f`, find the limits and use `cumtrapz`, and don't forget the negative sign :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a more mathematical solution, but

( \int_1^0 f(t) dt ) + ( \int_0^x f(t) dt )

is equivalent to the negative of

\int_x^1 f(t) dt

Thus, if you are able to find \int_0^x f(t) dt, you should be ablue to find what you seek.

Hopefully that helps.

(Excuse any syntax errors, I am not familiar with the syntax. This is meant to be a mathematical solution, there may be better programmatical solutions)

**EDIT:** As clarification, this was noted in a comment above (thanks to @Rody Oldenhuis for the clarification):

"I believe it's a consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus [FTC] that for any real-valued function `f` and limits `a` and `b`, `int(f, a,b) == -int(f, b,a)`. So indeed, ... use `flipud` or `fliplr` on your `f`, find the limits and use `cumtrapz`, and don't forget the negative sign :)"

In fact, this is true - this property is a consequence of the Second Part of the FTC, as long as `f` is real-valued over the interval `[a,b]` (note that `f` *does not* need to be continuous). Furthermore, the sum property, which I noted above, is also a consequence of the Second FTC: `int(f, a,b) + int(f, b,c) == int(f, a,c)`.